# OWL-CAROUSEL2 with images caption

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

This question was originally asked by Shaken in 2015.
I did what answered there, but the debugger tells me that the events are never fired, so nothing happens, despite the carousel works great.
Here is the relevant code:

```
$("#selvigallery").owlCarousel({
    singleItem : true,
    ...
        onInitialized : function(event){
            var activeImg = $('.owl-carousel').find('.active').find('img');
            var title = activeImg.attr('title');
            if(title) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4>');
        },
        onChanged : function(event){
            var activeImg = $('.owl-carousel').find('.active').find('img');
            var title = activeImg.attr('title');
            if(title) $('.image-caption').html('<h4>'+title+'</h4>');
        },
    //Transitions
    transitionStyle : "fade"

});
```

Setting breakpoints on the 2 events they are never reached.
What am I missing?

Comment: I think it would be helpful to isolate this in a jsfiddle/bin with the complete html/css/js that is supposed to work.

Comment: Sorry lynx, unfortunately I'm quite a begginer here and I don't know how to do a 'jsfiddle/bin'. Anyway the carousel operates perfectly, so I assume that the all the JS dipendencies (Foundation6 + OWL-carousel+JQuery) are correct. I add another piece o information: the OWL plugin is inside a '$(document).ready(function(){'.  If it can help a could provide the link to the online page (it is still in a testing area right now)

Comment: I think you missed `translated.owl.carousel` event as mentioned in the answer. May be you have to check the answers  again. Here is the working example [Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Cerlin/3k4k23dn/2/) by @Cerlin Boss

Comment: I initially used the 'translated' event, then during tests I replaced it with 'initialized' which, in my opinion, should be always rised for sure. The problem here is that no events are ever rised. It could be some syntax error (but debugger says no) or I am missing some sort of events activation (but I followed what reported on Owl-Carousel site).

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
I don't why, but I made 2 changes after a lot of researches: the event which activate the caption replacement is the 'afterMove'. No one else does the job for me. The second issue was the 'addClassActive : true,', absolutely required for me. The final piece of code is:

```
`   addClassActive : true,

    afterMove: function(event) {
    var activeImg = $('.owl-carousel').find('.active').find('img');
    var title = activeImg.attr('title');
    if(title) $('.hotel-caption').text(title);
        },`
```

Hope it can help somone.